# How to place additional access-restrictions on a subdirectory in Apache?

Tags: authentication, apache-2.4

We have a list of "internal" IP-addresses and only allow access to the server (Location /) from that list:

```
<Location />
    Require ip x.x.x.x
    Require ip y.y.y.y
</Location>
```

I need to further restrict access to a sub-directory (Location /foo) to authenticated users (Require valid-user).

Whatever I do, I never get prompted for login to access /foo -- Apache simply grants me access, because my IP-address is on the list (for Location /).

I cycled through all three different values of AuthMerging (off, and, or) to no avail... Must be something really stupid :-/ Using httpd-2.4.6. Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Comment: For one, Vasili, the link you gave is for Apache-2.2, where auth mechanisms are quite different from 2.4. And then, of course, I've already read the 2.4 page on the subject -- to no avail. It is too basic and does not cover my case.